# Getting the timezone offset in Python from a timezone ignoring DST

Tags: python, datetime, timezone

What is the correct way to get an UTC offset from a timezone in python?
I need a function to send a pytz timezone and get the timezone offset ignoring the Daylight Saving Time.

```
import pytz
tz = pytz.timezone('Europe/Madrid')
getOffset(tz) #datetime.timedelta(0, 3600)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`pytz` timezone objects obey `tzinfo` [API specification](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.tzinfo.dst) defined in the `datetime` module. Therefore you can use their `.utcoffset()` and `.dst()` methods:

```
timestamp = datetime(2009, 1, 1)  # any unambiguous timestamp will work here

def getOffset(tz):
    return tz.utcoffset(timestamp) - tz.dst(timestamp)
```

Comment: Great answer.  To note why `timestamp` is still required, consider that many time zones have changed their *standard* time over the years.

Comment: Really useful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

also works nicely with Python 3.9 's [zoneinfo.ZoneInfo](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zoneinfo.html):

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from zoneinfo import ZoneInfo

def utc_offset_no_dst(dt: datetime, tz: ZoneInfo) -> timedelta:
    return tz.utcoffset(dt) - tz.dst(dt)

z = "Europe/Berlin" # +1 (DST=0) / +2 (DST=1)
tz = ZoneInfo(z)

for dt in datetime(2022,1,15), datetime(2022,6,15):
    print(utc_offset_no_dst(dt, tz))
    
# 1:00:00
# 1:00:00
```